# Как вывести параллелограмм и скошенный треугольник звездочками в java?

Tags: java, циклы, for

По заданию нужно вывести звездочками фигуры типа

```
*                       *************
 **                      *           *
  ***                     *           *
    ****                   *************
     ******
```

Как сделать их из обычного треугольника и квадрата?
код на прямоугольный треугольник

```
int count = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k + 1 < i + 1; k++) {
                System.out.print("*");
```

код на пустой квадрат

```
int count = 10;
for (int j =1; j <= count; j++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 1; i <= count - 2; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
            for (int j = 2; j <= count - 1; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= count; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: а где же пример вашего кода для остальных фигур? добавьте пример вашей реализации этих фигур

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Star Pattern Logic - Part 1 - By Naveen AutomationLabs
**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2eSm8WIXAw**
смотри и изучай, у него на канале много интересных фишек...

либо скачай на андройд **java pattern programs free**
там под 700 примеров кода для рисования фигур